# How do I deploy this docker app on digital ocean?

Tags: linux, network-programming, docker, digital-ocean

I set up a one-click docker server on DigitalOcean, then ssh'd into it as root@[Server IP] and ran the following

```
docker pull continuumio/memex-explorer
docker run -p 80:5000 continuumio/memex-explorer
```

Which outputs:

```
* Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd
...done.
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
* Restarting with reloader
```

Then when I navigate to [Server IP]:5000 it doesn't display anything. I expected it to present the landing page of the app.

I then ran

```
ufw allow 5000/tcp
ufw allow 80/tcp
ufw enable
```

but it didn't help.

Can anyone install and set up this app? There's a link to the source of the app I'm trying to run: [Here](https://github.com/memex-explorer/memex-explorer), and the docker image: [Here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/continuumio/memex_explorer/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just needed to run it in detached mode. 
I just provisioned a droplet on Digital Ocean and spun up the Docker image with this run command:

`sudo docker run -d -p 80:5000 --name memex continuumio/memex_explorer`

There is no need to change any firewall settings. 
Make sure the container is active:

`sudo docker ps`

It should display something like this:

`64242f576c16  continuumio/memex_explorer:latest   "/root/memex-explore   35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes       22/tcp, 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->5000/tcp   memex`

To see the application running, just type the Digital Ocean [Server IP]  into the URL for the browser. The port is redirected to port 80 so no need to type it in.

You can attach to the container and look around (the Dockerfile is available in the image as well).

`sudo docker exec memex bash`

Comment: are you using the digitalocean docker application or are you running like an ubuntu os and installed docker manually? because i'm trying the solution you provided and it didn't work for me. no page is displaying

Comment: I did use the Docker application prebuilt from Digital Ocean. I forgot to include the options for connecting via docker exec. The exact command I used to connect to the running docker instance is:

docker exec -it memex bash